# How to get number of login successes & failures while running Listener

Tags: jmeter

I am doing proxy recording. We are doing load test for web-application which contains username & password.

How to differentiate the login success & login failure?

I need to get the number of login successes & failures while running Listener.

Can you please share me the steps I have to follow.

Comment: Just answered  this here 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573502/how-to-count-failed-requests-with-jmeter/14577567#14577567][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573502/how-to-count-failed-requests-with-jmeter/14577567#14577567

Answer (score 0):

Add a response assertion to you request to check some content in response body or code

- use aggregate report and you will have error %