# How to count failed requests with jmeter

Tags: httprequest, jmeter, stress-testing

I am running `JMeter` and I want a count of all the failed requests that either timed out, or, just plain failed. I see that some of the listeners show that there have been failures, but none see to have a field that displays the total number of failed requests versus successful requests. Does anyone know how I can easily get this data without having to count each failure by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add timeout to your sampler
- Add assertions on code and response content
- Use aggregate report

You should have these figures

Comment: These terms are sounding very vague to me. If you can then please direct me to a link, where it explains how to exactly achieve that. Thanks

Comment: @UBIK, Why don't you use summary report instead of aggregate report?

Answer (score 7):

To check the number of failed responses go through following steps:

1) `Add >> Listener >> View result tree >> select the check box of 'Errors'` It will only capture responses with failed messages not of success
With this you can check response message, sent request in detail![enter image description here][1]

And if you want to know about total count of failed requests and average time,max time then go through following steps:

2)  `Add >> Listener >> Summary Report >> select the check box of 'Errors'` It will only capture summary report of requests with failed responses not of success

Answer (score 4):

**Add the Aggregate report to the thread group.Which gives you total transaction count and the  " Error % ". So that you can know about the number of failed transactions**

If you want to know particular failure scenario then add the Assertion with the request. In the assertion just mention the scenario you want to check.

- - Aggregate report
  - Assertion**